# Turn Prezi frames into solid colour - css code

Tags: css, colors, prezi

I'm looking to turn frames in Prezi into solid colour.  They're currently transparent.  This is the CSS code.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Danielle

```
circle
{
borderAlpha: 1;
gradEndAlpha: 1;
gradStartAlpha: 1;
lockTintAlpha: 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was only using circles so I manipulated the `frame.rectangle` so I could use background gradients and borders. Increasing the radius to 900 and then changing the `grad` properties.

```
frame.rectangle
{
    borderAlpha: 1;
    borderColor: #318bff;
    borderThickness: 10;
    gradEndAlpha: .9;
    gradEndColor: #ccc;
    gradStartAlpha: .9;
    gradStartColor: #fff;
    radius: 900;
   thickness: 3;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.  the key is setting the gradEndColor and gradStartColor parameters.  by default there's a color set but this doesn't do the job..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, circles are meant to only be outlines. So in order to make them solid, you need to set the `thickness` to be significantly higher. I achieved a solid yellow circle like so:

```
frame.circle
{
    gradEndAlpha: 1;
    gradEndColor: #ffe633;
    gradStartAlpha: 1;
    gradStartColor: #ffe633;
    thickness: 100;
}
```

Set `gradEndColor` and `gradStartColor` to the color you'd like - http://www.colorpicker.com/ should help you find the hexadecimal code (#123456) to replace it with!